# Is it Undefined behavior to change an object and use it in the same expression but the subexpressions are separated by comma operator?

Tags: c++, comma-operator

Hello I have found this program on some website. What confuses me is that this program modifies the same object and uses it in the same expression thus is it Undefined Behavior? or it is ok because the Comma operator `,` Guarantees evaluation from left-to-right?

```
int x = 10, y;

// The following is equavalent to y = x++ 
y = (x++, printf("x = %d\n", x), ++x, printf("x = %d\n", x), x++);

// Note that last expression is evaluated 
// but side effect is not updated to y 
printf("y = %d\n", y);
printf("x = %d\n", x);
```

The output:

```
x = 11
x = 12
y = 12
x = 13
```

Comment: That first comment is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> Comma operator , Guarantees evaluation from left-to-right?

Yes, with a caveat. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its result is discarded (although if it has class type, it won't be destroyed until the end of the containing full expression), and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression `E2` begins

The caveat:

> (note that a user-defined operator, cannot guarantee sequencing) (until C++17).

The caveat does not apply to your case since you are not using any user defined comma operator function.

---

Unless you are in the business of stress-testing a compiler, you should never write code like that.  Use simpler, more obviously understood, code.

```
x++;
printf("x = %d\n", x);

++x;
printf("x = %d\n", x);

x++;
y = x;
```